# Notation is confusing me (sufficiency principle)

Tags: self-study, notation

This example (from a book) illustrates the sufficiency principle and I will write it down so that you get some context :

Let $\boldsymbol{X} = (X_1,X_2..,X_n)$ be a sample of independent Bernoulli variables with probability function (pdf):

$$p(\boldsymbol{x};\theta) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{i=n}\theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i} = \theta^{k}(1-\theta)^{n-k}$$ where $k = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\,.$

Consider the statistic$$T = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \sim \mathcal{Bin}(n,\theta)$$with $P^T(k;\theta)=\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k} $.

EDIT: The statistic $T$ generates a partition of the sample space $\mathcal{X} = \bigcup_{k=0}^{n} \mathcal{X}_k$ with$$\mathcal{X}_k = \left\{(x_1,x_2...,x_n):k = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \right\}$$

EDIT:The conditional distribution of $\boldsymbol{X}$ given $T=k$ is a distribution with support $\mathcal{X}_k$. Thus for $x \in \mathcal{X}_k = \{x': \sum_i x_i' =k \}$

$$\dfrac{P_{\theta}\{ \{\boldsymbol{x}\} \cap \mathcal{X}_k \}}{P_{\theta}^T(\{k \})}= \dfrac{p(\boldsymbol{x};\theta)}{p^T(k;\theta)} = \dfrac{\theta^{k}(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}\qquad\boldsymbol{(1)}$$

However, the notation in  $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ is a bit confusing. I am trying to compare to what I would have written it as: (is this right?)

$$\dfrac{P_{\theta} \{\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{x} \cap T (\boldsymbol{X})=k \} }{P\{ T(\boldsymbol{X})= k \} } = \dfrac{p(\boldsymbol{x};\theta)}{p^T(k;\theta)} = \dfrac{\theta^{k}(1-\theta)^{n-k}}{\binom{n}{k}\theta^k(1-\theta)^{n-k}}\qquad\boldsymbol{(2)}$$

Anyhow why does the author use the set notation $\{\boldsymbol{x}\} $  ? I have the same question for $\{k\} $ and also about $\{ \boldsymbol{x} \} \cap \mathcal{X}_k $ and these things are embedded in :

$$\dfrac{P_{\theta}\{ \{\boldsymbol{x}\} \cap \mathcal{X}_k \}}{P_{\theta}^T(\{k \})}$$

Comment: Sometimes authors use set notation when working with probabilities because probability can be viewed as a set function.  It's just a matter of taste, really.  Are you just wondering about notation or the sufficiency principle?

Comment: @Xi'an I can't find the book online just a preview:https://books.google.se/books?id=YjLSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=introduction+of+the+theory+of+statistical+inference+page+52+hannelore+liero&source=bl&ots=kfVX2avpjC&sig=LEC1w4XmCatP5W-lLCq4MkbSFPA&hl=sv&sa=X&ei=9OWaVfSEMcqeywPW-byYDw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=introduction%20of%20the%20theory%20of%20statistical%20inference%20page%2052%20hannelore%20liero&f=false

Comment: @dsaxton well Iam trying to understand,for example, why he is using  $\{ \boldsymbol{x}\}$  I mean it is not the same as $\boldsymbol{X =x}$. He will use the same notation in other proofs and i would like to understand them too.

Comment: @Xi'an   I have added more which might be helpful

Comment: I think (1) is just used to identifiy your formluar there. Nothing special. ${ \boldsymbol{x}}$ is a set, which stand for points ${(x_1, x_2,...x_n)}$ I think if you read Robert Hogg's introduction to methematical statistical chapter 7.2 notations will be much clearer.

Comment: @Xi'an I just added (1) to refer to something

Comment: The notation $\{ \boldsymbol{x}\}$ is a set notation and the event $\{ \boldsymbol{x}\}$ is indeed equivalent to the event "$X=x$" when considering probabilities as measures on the collection of all subsets of $\Omega=\{ 0,1\}^n$. Similarly for $\{k\}$ which is a subset of $\Omega^T=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. Both $\boldsymbol{(1)}$ and $\boldsymbol{(2)}$ are equivalent. If anything, the set notation is more rigorous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Both forms of notation are informal shorthands for more rigorous ones.**

A [random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54894/919) $X$ is a (measurable) function defined on a sample space $\Omega$, with values in a real vector space $V$, endowed with a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ (on a sigma-algebra $\mathfrak{F}$),

$$X:\Omega\to V.$$

We may ignore all details of the parenthesized conditions about measurability and a sigma-algebra, but they should remind us that probabilities are numbers assigned to *events*, which are subsets of $\Omega$, not *outcomes*, which are elements of $\Omega$.

In the context of the question $\Omega$ has not been specified but would, in practice, be the set of all possible outcomes of a sequence of $n$ binary experiments.  The process of *encoding* those outcomes with zeros and ones, with the intention of performing arithmetic operations on those values, is what creates the random variable $X$. Although its values are in the strictest sense only elements of $\{0,1\}^n = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\,|\, x_i\in\{0,1\}\}$, in order to make sense of sums, averages, and other arithmetic combinations of them we automatically--with no further announcement--consider them to be elements of $\mathbb{R}^n = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)\,|\, x_i\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

**Notice the use of conventional [mathematical set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).**  This abbreviates more formal descriptions of sets, which themselves are permitted by virtue of the [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema).  This axiom schema is essentially a set of templates that assert the meaningfulness of defining a set as consisting of elements of a given set that satisfy some additional logical condition.  The corresponding notation is of the form

$$\{x\in A\,|\, P(x)\}$$

where $A$ is a set and $P$ is a logical predicate (that is, will be definitely true or false for any element of $A$).  Although $P$ can have any logical form, in the instances below it typically is an assertion that something is an element of some set; that is, "$P(x)$" is in the form "$x\in B$", or else it is an assertion that some function attains a specified value; that is, "$P(x)$" is in the form "$f(x) = y$" for a given function $f$ and possible value $y$.

**Continuing with the question,** we can identify the *statistic* $T$ as a real-valued function

$$T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$$

Consequently, *via* functional composition and an abuse of notation, "$T$" is also used to represent the random variable indicated in this schematic:

$$T\circ X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R};\\T\circ X(\omega) = T(X(\omega)).$$

**We are now in a position to translate the informal language of the question into these more rigorous terms.**

1. "$T$ generates a partition of the sample space... ."  For each $k\in\mathbb{R}$, define

   $$\mathcal{X}_k = \left(T\circ X\right)^{-1}(k) = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, T\circ X(\omega) = k\}.$$

   This is a subset of $\Omega$. It is an event because $T$ is (obviously) measurable, whence $T\circ X$ is measurable.

   **In words:** $\mathcal{X}_k$ is the set of outcomes (event) for which the statistic $T$ has the value $k$.
2. "$\{\boldsymbol{x}\} \cap \mathcal{X}_k$" clearly is intended as a set intersection. We know what the second set is.  The first is a very informal shorthand for

   $$``\{\boldsymbol{x}\}" = X^{-1}(\{\boldsymbol{x}\}) = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, X(\omega)\in\{\boldsymbol{x}\} \} = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, X(\omega)=\boldsymbol{x}\}.$$

   Notice the two different meanings of "$\{\boldsymbol{x}\}$"! The correct, mathematically conventional meaning  used in the middle is that of a (singleton) subset of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. The intended meaning of the shorthand on the left is that of an event in $\Omega$.

   Since $\{\boldsymbol{x}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable, $\{\boldsymbol{x}\}\subset \Omega$ is an event.  (How's that for a confusing statement?!)

   **In words:**  $\{\boldsymbol{x}\}$ is the set of outcomes (event) where $X$ has the particular value $X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, \ldots, X_n=x_n$.
3. "$\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{x} \cap T (\boldsymbol{X})=k$" is a little clearer, being a bit more explicit.  It would be interpreted as the intersection of

   $$``\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{x}" = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, X(\omega)=\boldsymbol{x}\}$$

   and

   $$``T (\boldsymbol{X})=k" = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, T(X(\omega)) = k\}.$$

   **In words:** These are the same two events described in (2) and (1) above, respectively.
4. "$P_{\theta}^T(\{k \})$" contains a lot of baggage, but the key part is the interpretation of "$\{k\}$" in the context of the superscript "$^T$".  This is intended to refer to the event

   $$``\{k\}" = \left(T\circ X\right)^{-1}(k) = \{\omega\in\Omega\,|\,T\circ X(\omega) = k\}.$$

   **In words:** $P_{\theta}^T(\{k \})$ is the probability (according to some probability measure $\mathbb{P}_\theta$ as defined on $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F})$) that $T$ will have the value $k$.

**The informal rule** that seems to be operating in (2) and (4) is to abbreviate expressions of the form "$\{\omega\in\Omega\,|\, Z(\omega)= y\}$", where $Z$ is a random variable and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ or $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, in favor of some notation that mentions only "$Z$" and "$y$".

**This is enough of a concordance to decipher the quotations in the question and to see the equivalence in the intended meanings**.  Although the mathematically more rigorous notation is more explicit, and (hopefully) less subject to misinterpretation, it also grows cumbersome and--taken to an extreme--becomes almost unreadable.  Good expository writing is a compromise between being explicit and being readily understandable.

---

#### Reference

Halmos, Paul, *Naive Set Theory.* Princeton, NJ: D. Van Nostrand Company, 1960. Reprinted by Springer-Verlag, New York, 1974.